# Decrementing a number in MongoDb column from vue js on click function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have a function onclick in Vue js, what I'm trying to do is when that button that contains that function is clicked decrement a value (items in stock), everything works fine but when the page is loaded the value returns to its first state.
So I want to be able to decrement the value in MongoDB too to display the decremented number.

```
    <input type="submit" @click="decrease(product)" class="btn btn-warning btn-user btn-block" value="Send">`
```

Only {{product.stock}} items left in stock!

`

*this is the button*
*and this is the number "stock" coming from database*

```
decrease(product) {
    product.stock--;
    axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/products`)
    if(product.stock == 0){
        alert("No items in stock");
    }
}
```

*this is the function if anyone has a solution please help!*

Comment: You probably want to check if the stock is 0 before decrementing it and can you please show what you have tried so far to save the stock?

Comment: You are not doing anything in DataBase.

Comment: no the stock is 5 coming from database , i've tried axios put method but it doesn't work @AndreNuechter

Comment: I think the post-method would be the better choice. Can you update the question and include the part making the request? It would probably help answering your question...

Comment: Just done editing , hope this helps ! @AndreNuechter

Comment: You're not posting any data! The signature looks like `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`...